# .htaccess - Allow Requests to Certain URL & Block All Others if Referrer is Equal To

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to block all requests to my site if the referrer is equal to, for example, siteb.com UNLESS the URL being requested is equal to mysite.com/pagex/?random-variable

So if the referrer is siteb.com and the URL being requested is anything other than mysite.com/pagex/?random-variable, my .htaccess file should block the request, otherwise it should be allowed through.  If the referrer is not siteb.com, nothing should be done.

I've gotten as far as this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} siteb\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

However that just blocks ALL requests when the referrer is siteb.com.  I need to allow requests to mysite.com/pagex/?random-variable when the referrer is siteb.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more condition to your rule to allow `/pagex/?random-variable`:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} siteb\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/pagex?random-variable [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```